# Set Focus Requiring Debugging every time

Tags: vba, excel, userform, setfocus

I have created a `set focus`option in a `userform` before. However this time I am having some issues and was wondering if someone could please assist. I believe that the issue exists because I am using `pages` on my `userform`, whereas usually I would not.

My `userform` has 4 pages for the 4 different sections required. I want it so that if I was to leave a field blank to `setfocus` on said field. However when this is occuring I am getting runtime error '2110'End, Debug.

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Master Data")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

If Me.BDM.Value = "" Then
    Me.BDM.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please Enter BDM"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: It is not clear at what line are you getting this error ? is it in `iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1` ?

Comment: What is BDM ? a text control or check box or something else ?

Comment: @MukulVarshney sorry for the delay getting back. The BDM is a textbox in the userform which is located on page1 of the userform

Comment: Is the text box BDM visible? Or the page1 visible? They should be visible to get focus.

Comment: @MukulVarshney yes definitely visible in both cases. I did have the drop down to Exact Match which I wouldn't normally have, and trialed changing that back which also did not work.

Comment: Posted a solution to your `Error 2110` issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid error 2110 by showing `Page1` at top of Multipage control**

You'll have to make the textbox control visible by activating `Page1` before triggering `SetFocus`.

**Relevant code**

This code example assumes that your `BDM` textbox is located on the first page (=index 0) of a multipage control named `MultiPage1`.
By **choosing `Page1`** via `Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0` you **avoid** that Excel *interprets* the control as **invisible** and raises error 2110.

Furthermore it will be necessary to actually activate focus by a trick after displaying the messagebox (via subsequent hiding/showing of userform).

```
If Me.BDM.Value = "" Then
  'Choose Page1 to allow view without error 2110
   Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0  ' << avoid error 2110 by activating Page1
   MsgBox "Please Enter BDM"
   Me.BDM.SetFocus
   Me.Hide: Me.Show         ' activate above set focus
   Exit Sub
End If
```